# Automate database creation with incremental name?

Tags: php, python, wordpress

I am trying to think through a script that I need to create. I am most likely going to be using php unless there would be a better language to do this with e.g. python or ror. I only know a little bit of php so this will definitely be a learning experience for me and starting fresh with a different language wouldn't be a problem if it would help in the long run.

What I am wanting to do is create a website where people can sign up for WordPress hosting. Right now I have the site set up with WHMCS. If I just leave it how it is I will have manually go in and install WordPress every time a customer signs up. I would like an automated solution that creates a database and installs WordPress as soon as the customer signs up. With WHMCS I can run a script as soon as a customer signs up and so far I understand how to create a database, download WordPress, and install WordPress. The only thing is I can't figure out how to make it work with more than one customer because with each customer there will be a new database. What I need the script to do is when customer A signs up,  the script will create a database name "customer_A" (that name is just an example) and when, lets say my second customer signs up, the script will create a database named "customer_B".

Is there a possible solution to this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you've thought of?

Comment: Well, the same script will run each time a customer signs up. Because the same script will run each time, it will try to create a database with the same name/credentials each time. Customer_A signs up and a database is created named customer_a because that's what the script says to do. When customer_B signs up, a database will be created but it will have the same name/credentials, that is, it's name will be "customer_a". I need a way for the created database to be a different name each time a new customer signs up.

Comment: And you can't pass any information to this script?

Comment: Well, I am sure I could but I am not sure how I would or what that would look like.

Comment: Then you don't have a programming question, you have a WHMCS question.

Comment: Oh ok, so you are saying something like, just grab the clients last name or some other detail and append it to the database name?

Comment: Sure. The application doesn't actually care what you call the database, so long as it knows the name.

Comment: Technically that would work but the api doesn't have a function to call individual details of the customer. You can get a list of customer details but not individual details.

Answer (score 0):

I did this yesterday.

my process was to add a row to a master accounts table, get the auto inc id, use that along with the company name to create the db name. so in my case the db's are

Root_1companyname1
Root_2companyname2
..

Root_ is optional of course.

Ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok, I think I might understand but could you expound upon that a little more?

Comment: what specify do you need help with, hat part of the process?

Comment: Ok I guess, specifically, what code did you use to get the auto inc id and pass that to the database name when you created the database?

Comment: mysql_insert_id() returns the id

Comment: Ok so to create the database I use $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE my_db'; Would I just do something like $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE mysql_insert_id()';?

Comment: please don't ask if some bit of code will work, test it and see.

Comment: Oh I know that exact code won't work I was more or less asking if that was correct placement for mysql_insert_id(). I will go try some things out, thanks for the help.